# SQL Two result from one column in 2 columns

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, request

i have checked some similar issues in the forum but i can't seems to get it to work properly.
i'm on phpmyadmin

i need to get a result like that :

Reference | ProductNameEnglish | ProductNameFrench

What's blocking me is to do 2 requests on the same column (pl.name) :/

Here is my query for now :

```
SELECT
p.reference AS Reference,

(SELECT pl.name
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
WHERE p.active = 1
AND pl.id_lang = 2) AS ENname,

(SELECT pl.name
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
WHERE p.active = 1
AND pl.id_lang = 1) AS FRname

FROM ps_product p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the join in the subqueries:

```
SELECT p.reference AS Reference,
       (SELECT pl.name
        FROM ps_product_lang pl 
        WHERE p.id_product = pl.id_product AND
              p.active = 1 AND
              pl.id_lang = 2
       ) AS ENname,
       (SELECT pl.name
        FROM ps_product_lang pl 
        WHERE p.id_product = pl.id_product AND
              p.active = 1 AND
              pl.id_lang = 1
       ) AS FRname
FROM ps_product p;
```

This assumes that only one row matches the subqueries.  You may need to limit the results to a single row if that is not the case.

Comment: So the cause of my errors was about my JOINs, Thank you very much that work :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  p.reference AS Reference,
  pl.name as ENname,
  pf.name as FRname
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product and pl.id_lang = 1)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pf ON (p.id_product = pf.id_product and pf.id_lang = 2)
WHERE p.active = 1
```

I might have switched English and French, but that should be easy to fix....

Comment: I tried your sql request too, and that work like a charm, i didn't know we could add columns result like that, this will surely help me in the future, Thank you very much sir !